# python 2.6 scapy doesnt work after install everything

Tags: python, networking, scapy

this is what i get in windows 7 64bit cmd

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\Ran>scapy
INFO: Can't import python gnuplot wrapper . Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 765, in emit
    self.stream.write(fs % msg.encode("UTF-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 54: ordinal
 not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\\scapy", line 25, in <module>
    interact()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 278, in interact
    scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arch import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 79, in <modu
le>
    from windows import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 214,
 in <module>
    ifaces.load_from_dnet()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 166,
 in load_from_dnet
    for i in pcapdnet.dnet.intf():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dnet'
```

what can i do?its something with dnet but i already installed cersion matched dnet to pythion 2.6